# Restriccion acceso a recursos, imagenes en hosting compartido

Tags: webservice, iis

Quisiera consultar la mejor practica para servir recursos de imagenes desde un hosting compartido a través de un servicio web pero que estos recursos no se puedan ver a través de una url

Entiendo que podria bloquearse el listado de las carpetas del sitio web y de sus archivos, pero conociendo la url podrian ser accesibles. Quiza usando web.config o .htaccess

Me gustaria saber si alguien ha tratado esta tarea y como lo ha resuelto.

gracias